# Format a Thumb drive with an OS Partition

Tags: partition, udisks

I have a thumb drive with a partion containing a bootable POP-OS image.  I'd like to reclaim this space and just use as a thumb drive, but in "Disks" utility in POP_OS, if I try to delete:

> "Error deleting partition /dev/sdg1: Failed to get partition '1' on
> device /dev/sdg (udisks-error-quark, 0)"

If I try to format:

> "This partition cannot be modified because it contains a partition
> table; please reinitialize layout of the whole device
> (udisks-error-quark, 11)"

I am a linux amateur and toasted my last thumb drive so I am being cautious.  How to make it one big partition?

Comment: Use `dd` to wipe the first few blocks of the USB.  Try `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdg bs=512 count=100`

Comment: It will probably work with `dd` according to fpmurphy's advice, but it is risky, because there is no final checkpoint. A minor typing error is enough to damage valuable data. I suggest that you use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) for this purpose.

Comment: @sudodus.  What you you mean by "there is no final checkpoint"?

Comment: @fpmurphy, `dd` will start doing what you tell it to do without any question. It does not ask for a confirmation (at a 'final checkpoint'), where you can double-check, that the command points to the correct target device.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes  it is very difficult to wipe drive with OS partition, especially bootable drives. You can easily do this by using `wipefs` command. 
Open terminal, check the partitions available in your drive by running 
`fdisk -l` This will list all the devices mounted on your system and their details. 
Your drive should be listed as `/dev/sd...`, be very sure of the block device name of the drive you are erasing because any changes made would be irreversible. 
Forcefully erase the disk by running 
`wipefs -a -f /dev/your_block_device_name` 
After the above operations, you can now easily format the GNOME  Disks desktop application, click on  <kbd>Disks</kbd>  » <kbd>Drive Name</kbd> » Right click on <kbd>Settings Icon</kbd> » <kbd>Format Partition</kbd>  
**GOOD LUCK !**

Answer (score 0):

Read this first to understand your situation:

You may be facing this error because a partition table may have been created inside this partition and now it has **subpartitions**. The **partition** can be loop mounted and recognized as a full drive containing **subpartitions** inside it. One way to create this environment is to run:
`parted /dev/sdg1` and force it to consider the **partition** as a complete device. After you're inside `parted` you would run `mktable msdos` to create an MBR partition table and after this you will be able to create **subpartitions**.

Now you may understand what happened, here's a possible solution. An easy way to clear a partition table is to write at the beginning of the device. You can do it in Unix-like systems by using the command `dd`. Giving specific parameters for it to wipe just the partition table:

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/your/partition bs=1048576 count=1`

This command will read zeroes from "/dev/zero" 1048576 bytes at a time (1MB total) and do it only once. The first 1MB of an MBR disk contains info about the partitions and a bootloader in case the disk has an OS installed in it. A sane partition creation procedure will always jump the first 1MB of data in the disk and create the first partition after it in order to not corrupt or overwrite this valuable data.

In your specific case, you may change the example path to **/dev/sdg1** (the partition that has a partition table) and run the `dd` command, this way the program may no more find a partition table and proceed.